# what after WAL LSN value of type pg_lsn reach its limit

Tags: postgresql, replication, clustering, high-availability, patroni

I am trying to determine the optimal Standby for automated failover based on the highest value of `pg_last_wal_receive_lsn()` of all slaves. But what if `max_wal_size` is reached, does `pg_lsn` values go to 0?

Please suggest if there's any better approach to determine node with the best RPO out of all secondaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log sequence number (LSN) is never reset to 0, so you don't have to worry about that. There is no limit, and there is no connection to the parameter `max_wal_size`: that parameter governs when checkpoints are triggered and has no direct connection with the size of `pg_wal` or the LSN.

Comment: Thank you @Laurenz, this clarifies my doubt.

Comment: Could you please share some official document that describe so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `max_wal_size` can easily be found in the documentation and is well described there. I doubt that you will find it spelled out anywhere that the log sequence number is never reset unless you use `pg_resetwal`, but it should be obvious from the source code, which is as official as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

Laurenz's answer is mostly correct, but is technically wrong on one important point.  There is a limit, which is at the end of unsigned 64-bit address space.  This means you have around 18 exabytes of life-time write capacity on a single PostgreSQL database.  After that point, I assume that PostgreSQL would be unable to write log segments after and effectively stop working.  We can call that limit "the end of history."

Before you reach that point, you could logically replicate the database to another cluster and start over.  However to my knowledge nobody has ever even come close to that limit.  The limit is currently well out of reach of all current users of Postgres, but at some point I assume this could change and then I assume PostgreSQL will come up with a workaround.